# How to Delete data in Multiple Tables Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my project, I’ve two Tables in Database 1st is my tickets table where tickets data is stored. and 2nd is gp_group where tickets ID is stored in gpid from tickets id. See the below image :- [Tickets table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kwAM.png)

and whenever I Delete a ticket then I have to delete ticket data from both tickets table and gp_group table for that ticket. See the below image :-[gp_group table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Kno.png)

Now, My problem is that I am not able to delete the ticket data from gp_group table but tickets table data is deleted.

So, I’ve used a function in my delete function to delete the data from both the table when I delete the ticket. But still not work.

Code in `TicketController`

```
public function destroy(Ticket $ticket)
{
  $ticket =DB::table('tickets')
 -> leftJoin('gp_group','tickets.id', '=','gp_group.ticket_id')
  -> where('tickets.id',$ticket);
  DB::table('gp_group')->where('ticket_id',$ticket)->delete();
  $ticket->delete(); 
  
    return redirect()->route('tickets.index')
                    ->with('success','Group deleted successfully');
}
```

I get this error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string"

And trying other code in function

```
public function destroy(Ticket $ticket)
{ 
  $ticket->delete();
  ticket::where("id", $ticket)->delete();
  gp_group::where("gpid", $ticket)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('tickets.index')
                    ->with('success','Group deleted successfully');
}
```

But still not work.

i get different error

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'rp1.gp_groups' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `gp_groups` where
> `gpid` =
> {"id":63,"gpname":"Nasser","detail":"Nasser","gender":"Male","semester":432,"status":"Not
> assigned","Assigned":null,"user_id":1,"track_id":5,"created_at":"2021-10-15T18:50:04.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-15T18:50:04.000000Z"})"

I would be very thankful if anyone could point-out mistake I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solve to your issue, you need to pass only the Id to the where function
Not the whole ticket like this

```
-> where('tickets.id',$ticket->id);
```

here is the full updated function

```
{ 
 $ticket->delete();
 gp_group::where("gpid", $ticket->id)->delete();

return redirect()->route('tickets.index')
                ->with('success','Group deleted successfully');
}
```

and you may consider foreign keys for that task, it will delete the `gp_group` record automatically whenever its ticket is deleted
read more about it [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/)

Comment: I tried to make a foreign key between these two tables But I face an error that is (Error creating foreign key on gpid (check data types) ). both data types in the table for id its integer.

Comment: yes, you need to change the `gbid` to `unsignedBigInteger()` in the schema of the `gb_group` table.
and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to create in your table a foreign key to `delete on cascade`:

[foreign-key-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

And then you can delete the parent registry (`tickets` table) and with that automatically will delete all items with the reference in the `gp_group` table the registries of the other table.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy(Ticket $ticket)
{
  $ticket =DB::table('tickets')
 -> leftJoin('gp_group','tickets.id', '=','gp_group.ticket_id')
  -> where('tickets.id',$ticket)->first();
}
```

I think you are missing to add first()

So it will take only one low instead and if you need to delete multiple record you would pass them in roop

Comment: It just returns ''group deleted successfully'' without deleting from both tables